# Is there any way to know which xml file is not being used in our project

Tags: android, android-xml

However this is not a logical question still i am much interested to know if i have any idle file that i am not using in my project.Sometime after a long project we just dont recognize that which is the actual file and which is the copy of it.Sometime we just create some xml files to check the layout and other effects like selector or some custom drawable.I mean though these file never be get executed still it crates logical confusion when we get back to our code about true identity and use of the file.

I read that Proguard removes all unused files before making apk file.Does it remove all these xml files also ?

I am bit new about proguard concept.
Thanks.

Comment: if you find out anything about this please share it i want to clean my project too :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AndroidLint, tool who scan your project and return a lot of advices, and then, all unused resources !

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

```
- Missing translations (and unused translations)
- Layout performance problems (all the issues the old layoutopt tool used to find, and more)
- Unused resources
- Inconsistent array sizes (when arrays are defined in multiple configurations)
- Accessibility and internationalization problems (hardcoded strings, missing contentDescription, etc)
- Icon problems (like missing densities, duplicate icons, wrong sizes, etc)
- Usability problems (like not specifying an input type on a text field)
- Manifest errors
```

Comment: Note: Android Lint is a new tool introduced in ADT 16 (and Tools 16). I posted a few seconds after you :)

Comment: I saw your answer :), more complete than mine... Thanks

Comment: There is also a tool in Android Studio now under refactor called remove unused resources that does this check as well.